# Scrollable vertical list of text box inputs using Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt, jcomponent

I'm trying to build a simple interface for an assignment, in which multi-line word-wrapped input boxes can be stacked vertically in a single, fixed-width column. then the whole stack (if tall enough) has to scroll vertically inside of a scroll pane with the same fixed width and a fixed height.

The active box has to change height dynamically to fit the amount of text as it is being typed/deleted. This means the y position of all subsequent inputs in the column should change accordingly. A layout manager's job, right?

I started reading about the swing layouts, and it seemed like only the GridBagLayout could do this. Since this is my app's only interface window, it seemed like a clunky layout to achieve something simple.

So, which swing layout should I use, along with which text input class for word-wrapping and auto height adjustment? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, BoxLayout ended up doing the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) might be what you are after for this use-case.